# Connectedness of Hartogs' Triangle in $\mathbb C^2$

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, connectedness, path-connected

> Show that arbitrary $(z_1,z_2)$ in the Hartogs' triangle $$\triangle_H = \{(z_1,z_2) \in \Bbb C^2: |z_1| < |z_2| < 1\}$$ can be joined by a path (in $\triangle_H$) to $w =  (0,r)$ for some fixed $r\in \mathbb R \cap (0,1)$ in each of the following cases:
>
> 1. $0 < r \le |z_1| < |z_2| < 1$
> 2. $0\le |z_1| \le r \le |z_2| < 1$
> 3. $0\le |z_1| < |z_2| \le r < 1$
>
> Conclude that $\triangle_H$ is an open **connected** subset of $\mathbb C^2$.

I don't see why it is required to consider all the three cases above to prove the path connectedness (which implies connectedness) of $\triangle_H$. If we can show the requirement for any one case, we will have a paths $\gamma_1, \gamma_2$ between $(z_1,z_2)$ & $(0,r)$, and $(z_1',z_2')$ & $(0,r)$ respectively, for arbitrary $(z_1,z_2), (z_1',z_2') \in \triangle_H$. Then, we can simply consider $\gamma_1 \ast \overline{\gamma_2}$ to get a path from $(z_1,z_2)$ to $(z_1',z_2')$ in $\triangle_H$.  In the first case, I thought of considering $\gamma: I = [0,1]\to \mathbb C^2$ given by $\gamma(t):= ((1-t)z_1, (1-t)z_2 + tr)$ but it doesn't seem to be true that $\gamma(I) \subset \triangle_H$ in this case.

How should I construct the required paths in each of the three cases? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't see why it is required to consider all the three cases

These cases don't look particular useful to me. Just use polar coordinates $z_k=r_k e^{i\varphi_k}; k=1,2$. Rotating the complex point doesn't change the condition $|z_1|<|z_2|$. The map $t\mapsto (r_1 e^{i\varphi_1\cdot t},r_2 e^{i\varphi_2\cdot t})$ defines a path from $(r_1,r_2)$ to $(z_1,z_2)$. Two real point in Hartog's Triangle are easily connected by a path.

Comment: Thanks! Perhaps the path you have in mind from $(z_1,z_2)$ to $(|z_1|,|z_2|)$ is $f:I\to \triangle_H$ given by $f(t) = (|z_1|e^{i(1-t)\varphi_1}, |z_2|e^{i(1-t)\varphi_2})$, right?

Comment: I don't see it yet - how are two real points in $\triangle_H$ connected by a path? To determine the exact equation of the path, I think the three cases will play a role.

Comment: @connected-subgroup Yes, I forgot "t" while copy&paste. Two real points in $\Delta_H$ can be connected by a straight line. You just need to verify that it is contained in $\Delta_H$.

Comment: Straight lines are okay for cases $(2), (3)$, but for $0 < r \le |z_1| < |z_2| < 1$ we need to be more careful. Although a union of two straight lines will do the job here.

Comment: I disagree. For $(r_1,r_2),(s_1,s_2)\in \Delta_H\cap \mathbb{R}^2$ and $0\leq t \leq 1$ you always have  $t(r_1,r_2)+(1-t)(s_1,s_2)\in\Delta_H$. Actually, I never used the point $(0,r)$.

Comment: Can you prove it? I only have $|tr_1 + (1-t)s_1| \le t|r_1| + (1-t)|s_1| < t|r_2| + (1-t)|s_2|$, but we need $|tr_1 + (1-t)s_1| < |tr_2 + (1-t)s_2|$ for all $0\le t\le 1$.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple way to see connectedness of Hartogs triangle.
observe that $(z_1, z_2)$ $\rightarrow$ $(z_1z_2, z_2)$ is continuous onto map from $\mathbb D \times \mathbb D^*$ to $\triangle_H.$
Since $\mathbb D \times \mathbb D^*$ is connected, so is $\triangle_H.$